# OpenXML SDK and MathML

Tags: openxml, docx, equation, mathml

I use MathML to create some data blocks and I need to insert it throught OpenXML SDK into docx file. I've heard it is possible, but I didn't manage it. Could somebody help me with this problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As far as I know, the OpenXml SDK does not support presentation MathML out of the box.

Instead, the OpenXml SDK supports Office MathML.
So, to insert presentation MathML into a word document we first have
to transform the presentation MathML into Office MathML.

Fortunately, Microsoft provides a XSL file (called *MML2OMML.xsl*)  to transform presentation MathML
into Office MathML. The file MML2OMML.xsl is located under `%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Office\Office12`. 
In conjunction with the .Net Framework class
`XslCompiledTransform` we are able to transform presentation MathML into Office MathML.

The next step is to create a `OfficeMath` object from the transformed MathML.
The `OfficeMath` class represents a run containing WordprocessingML which shall be handled as though it was Office Open XML Math.
For more info please refer to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-Us/library/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.officemath.aspx).

The presentation MathML does not contain font information. To get a nice result
we must add font information to the created `OfficeMath` object.

In the last step we have to add the `OfficeMath` object to our word document.
In the example below I simply search for the first `Paragraph` in a
word document called *template.docx* and add the `OfficeMath` object to the found paragraph.

```
XslCompiledTransform xslTransform = new XslCompiledTransform();

// The MML2OMML.xsl file is located under 
// %ProgramFiles%\Microsoft Office\Office12\
xslTransform.Load("MML2OMML.xsl");

// Load the file containing your MathML presentation markup.
using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(File.Open("mathML.xml", FileMode.Open)))
{
  using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
  {
    XmlWriterSettings settings = xslTransform.OutputSettings.Clone();

    // Configure xml writer to omit xml declaration.
    settings.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Fragment;
    settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = true;

    XmlWriter xw = XmlWriter.Create(ms, settings);

    // Transform our MathML to OfficeMathML
    xslTransform.Transform(reader, xw);
    ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(ms, Encoding.UTF8);

    string officeML = sr.ReadToEnd();

    Console.Out.WriteLine(officeML);

    // Create a OfficeMath instance from the
    // OfficeMathML xml.
    DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Math.OfficeMath om =
      new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Math.OfficeMath(officeML);

    // Add the OfficeMath instance to our 
    // word template.
    using (WordprocessingDocument wordDoc =
      WordprocessingDocument.Open("template.docx", true))
    {
      DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Paragraph par =
        wordDoc.MainDocumentPart.Document.Body.Descendants<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.Paragraph>().FirstOrDefault();        

      foreach (var currentRun in om.Descendants<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Math.Run>())
      {
        // Add font information to every run.
        DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.RunProperties runProperties2 =
          new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing.RunProperties();

        RunFonts runFonts2 = new RunFonts() { Ascii = "Cambria Math", HighAnsi = "Cambria Math" };        
        runProperties2.Append(runFonts2);

        currentRun.InsertAt(runProperties2, 0);
      }

      par.Append(om);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Very good solution @Hans. But how can i do the reverse. I want to convert the xml content of word file with OMML to plain text containing MML..!?

Comment: @serene: Please, see my answer to your question.

Comment: @Hans, Hi! thank you and it does work! I want to convert MathML to Open Xml Math as an addin in the Ribbon area by C#, but I can't find a method like "par.Append(om);" in PIA, and I don't know how to transform the WordprocessingDocument type to Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument type. Is there anyway to perform the same method in a addin or a right-click button which can real-time transform these MathMl into MS equation in bunches or one-by-one, thank you!

Comment: Most excellent and useful answer. A small change I made is searching for a math formula using Descendants<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Math.OfficeMath> as this will also find formula in a middle of the Paragraph. Thanks.

Comment: @Hans Apologies, I added a comment under a wrong question. I meant your answer to 16759100 about the opposite - importing a single equation from a Word document. Possibly this change might apply to this answer though.

Comment: @Hans, very useful answer! shall I install office to get it working? I want to use it in server. Thanks!